# Hilt NullPointerException onAttach by Preconditions.checkNotNull on Fragment

Tags: nullpointerexception, dagger-hilt, preconditions

I have fragment which extend Fragment
and I' m getting hilt error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:34)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper.<init>(ViewComponentManager.java:191)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.FragmentComponentManager.createContextWrapper(FragmentComponentManager.java:105)
        at main.Hilt_MyListFragment.initializeComponentContext(Hilt_MyListFragment.java:60)
        at main.Hilt_MyListFragment.onAttach(Hilt_MyListFragment.java:53)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1881)
        at lv.inbox.mailapp.widget.InboxFragment.onAttach(MyFragment.java:63)
```

MyFragment class:

```
abstract public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(LanguageContextWrapper.create(context, LanguageContextWrapper.getUserPreferLanguage(context)));
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

How to solve my error?

Answer (score 0):

this.context must be first

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        super.onAttach(LanguageContextWrapper.create(context, LanguageContextWrapper.getUserPreferLanguage(context)));
    }
```